# Check if string contains no duplicate characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I'm trying to check if all the characters in a string are unique. The following code keeps returning `true`. I suspect it's that the `if` condition keeps returning `false` unless the first 2 characters in the sorted list are the same.

Can someone help?

```
function checkifStringisUnique (str) {
  var chars = str.split('')
  var sortedChars = chars.sort()
  console.log(sortedChars)
  console.log(sortedChars.length)

  for (i=0; i < sortedChars.length; i++) {
    if (sortedChars[i] === sortedChars[i+1]) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'if a string is unique'?  You mean 'if all the characters within a string are unique'?

Comment: you know, this for loop is meaningless as a loop. its literally the same without the for loop part because it terminates instantly with either return true or false.

Comment: Let builtin types do the work for you: `return new Set(s).size === str.length;`

Comment: just another hint, you need to loop until the element before the last element, because you check the next element.

Answer (score 1):

Your `return true` statement is in the wrong place. It should be at the end of the function, but you have it at the end of your `for` loop.

This means that unless the first two characters of your sorted string are the same it would always return `true` incorrectly.

```
function checkifStringisUnique (str) {
  var chars = str.split('')
  var sortedChars = chars.sort()
  console.log(sortedChars)
  console.log(sortedChars.length)

  for (i=0; i < sortedChars.length; i++) {
    if (sortedChars[i] === sortedChars[i+1]) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}
```

A couple other miscellaneous things:

1. You should use semi-colons
2. You should ensure that you declare your variables so that they are not hoisted into the global scope (e.g. `var i=0` vs `i=0`)
3. You should stop looping at the second to last element, otherwise you will try to access an element outside of range of `sortedChars`
4. Consider what will happen when sorting a very large string and how that will affect the runtime of your function

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt help! Totally missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store unique values & compare its `size` with string's `length`.

```js
function checkifStringisUnique (str){
    var st = new Set();
    for(var i=0; i<str.length;i++)
      st.add(str[i]);

    console.log(str, "is unique: ",str.length == st.size);
}

checkifStringisUnique("abacd"); // false
checkifStringisUnique("abcd");  // true
```

Comment: I like this approach - very elegant and simple to understand

Answer (score 0):

## Observation

- The `return true` must be outside of your `for-loop`.

**This is your code with that fix.**  However, it's still a little wrong because you're making a comparison with `sortedChars[i + 1]` that could be `sortedChars[N + 1] = undefined`.

```js
function checkifStringisUnique(str) {
  var chars = str.split('')
  var sortedChars = chars.sort()
  console.log(sortedChars)
  console.log(sortedChars.length)

  for (i = 0; i < sortedChars.length; i++) {
    console.log(sortedChars[i + 1]);
    if (sortedChars[i] === sortedChars[i + 1]) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}

console.log(checkifStringisUnique('elzo'));
```

**This is a better approach and a fancy code:**

- In your `for-loop` use `i < sortedChars.length - 1` because you don't need to compare the last one character with `N+1`.

```js
function checkifStringisUnique(str) {
  var chars = str.split('')
  var sortedChars = chars.sort()
  console.log(sortedChars)
  console.log(sortedChars.length)

  for (i = 0; i < sortedChars.length - 1; i++) {
    console.log(sortedChars[i + 1]);
    if (sortedChars[i] === sortedChars[i + 1]) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}

console.log(checkifStringisUnique('elzo'));
console.log(checkifStringisUnique('eleazar'));
```

As you can see, now your loop is not making a comparison with the index `N+1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and a hash table for storing the found characters.

```js
function checkifStringisUnique(str) {
    var hash = Object.create(null);

    return str.split('').every(function (c) {
        return !hash[c] && (hash[c] = true);
    });
}

console.log(checkifStringisUnique('abc'));
console.log(checkifStringisUnique('aab'));
```